# How to find whether the file is open or close in Windows surface apps

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, microsoft-metro

I open a file using this code

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileToLaunch);
```

Now i have to check whether the file is in open or close mode.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean if launch actually worked which the method call result should tell you

```
Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file, options).then(
      function (success) {
        if (success) {

        } else {

        }
      });
```

after this, you probably won't be able to get info about status of the file.